# Set custom response headers on Spring Security authentication success URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0

After a [successful SAML 2.0 login](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/saml2/Saml2LoginConfigurer.html) on a [Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-saml2) application acting as service provider, I can redirect the user to a static success URL using:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.saml2Login(saml2Login -> saml2Login.defaultSuccessUrl(mySuccessUrl);
    }
}
```

How can I (dynamically) set these other pieces of information?

- URL parameters
- Response headers
- Cookies

So far, I found a (rather cumbersome) solution: set an [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) with a custom [RedirectStrategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/security/web/RedirectStrategy.html).

```
SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
handler.setDefaultTargetUrl(relayState);
handler.setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy() {
    @Override
    public void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String url) throws IOException {
        // do stuff ...
        // set response headers ...
        // set cookies ...
        // add a query string to the redirect URL ...
        super.sendRedirect(request, response, url);
    }
});
http.saml2Login(saml2Login -> saml2Login.successHandler(handler));
```

Are there better alternatives?

I am using Spring Boot 2.3 and Spring Security 5.2.